# Override PDF tax settings

Tags: php, magento-1.7

We override the Mage_Tax_Model_Config to have different tax settings for specific customer groups. Everything went well except for the PDF documents.

We checked the current customer group ID with $customer->getGroupId() where $customer is Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer();

Why this is don't work on the PDF documents? Please see the override class in detail:

```
public function displaySalesPricesInclTax($store = null)
{
    $customer = Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer();
    if ($customer->getGroupId() > 1) {
        return false;       
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public function displaySalesPricesExclTax($store = null)
{
    $customer = Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer();
    if ($customer->getGroupId() > 1) {
        return true;        
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: showing how you generate the PDFs would be of more use.

Comment: What do you mean? We generate the PDFs via the Magento backend. In my opinion the tax settings from System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax should work. Maybe the customer group ID cannot be retrieved on that point.